# Python: Opening a file with defined drive letter - TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, integer, typeerror, required

Here is my two lines of code:

```
drive = 'j:'
f = open("%s\sample", "wb", drive)
```

I'm trying to write a simple program that is writing to a file that is being created by the program, the file is to be created on a defined drive, in this case, just onto "J:", however the following is displayed when running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\FYP\Program\usb.py", line 2, in <module>
f = open("%s\sample", "wb", drive)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Feel free to check out the site tour under help --> site tour to learn about the site and earn a free badge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drive = 'j:'
f = open("%s\sample" % drive, "wb")
```

Guess this is what you want.

Comment: I knew it would be something so simple, that's what too much coffee does to my brain! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `with` to open your files as it will automatically close them and [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) may be less prone to simple errors:

```
drive = 'j:'
with open("{}/sample".format(drive), "wb", drive) as f:
     ..........
```

You should also use `/` or raw string `r` in your file paths as `\` is used to escape characters in python.

You can see how not doing so can have very different outcome:

```
In [38]: print "\new_dir"

ew_dir

In [39]: print "/new_dir"
/new_dir

In [40]: print r"\new_dir"
\new_dir
```

Comment: Good advice! I've never thought of doing this!